# Search for groups of first words

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table called 'fazerbem_dates' and dates are stored as follows:

```
09/08/2014 12:34:23 PM
09/08/2014 12:34:23 PM
09/08/2014 12:34:23 PM
10/08/2014 02:12:06 PM
10/08/2014 02:12:06 PM
10/08/2014 15:12:54 PM
```

And I'm picking dates for groups, as you can see in syntax below for sqlite3:

```
SELECT * FROM fazerbem_dates group by mine_dates
```

This syntax returns me only 3 rows:

```
09/08/2014 12:34:23 PM
10/08/2014 02:12:06 PM
10/08/2014 15:12:54 PM
```

he pulls the right way, but in my case I just wanted him to get the records by groups but with one exception: it only will consider only the first 10 letters of the string, thus making it return me only 2 records that are:

```
09/08/2014 12:34:23 PM
10/08/2014 02:12:06 PM
```

It is possible to do in sqlite syntax? If possible how I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
select min(fazerbem_dates)
from table t
group by substr(fazerbem_dates, 1, 10);
```